# How to install Huawei EC315 MTS Mblaze data card in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: usb-modem

I have bought MTS Mblaze Data card which is Huawei EC315 but I am not able to install it in my Ubuntu 14.04.

Please help.

Regards,
Sudhir

Answer (score 0):

make sure usb_modeswitch is installed. edit /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf and add below lines to the bottom:

```
#Huawei EC315
DefaultVendor=0x12d1
DefaultProduct=0x1f01

TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProductList="14db,14dc"
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

RUN:

`sudo usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf`

Device may be detected and configured from mass storage to cdma modem also reflected in product id(**14db instead of 1f01**). now run ifconfig command to see whether modem is configured as network-lan.

Try to check whether network manager(modem manager) applet is showing your connection under Mobile broadband. if not, you have to use wvdial to dial and connect. you can find configuring wvdial in a quick search. do reply if it works.

Comment: i am also having the same problem do not works in 64 bit ubuntu 14.04